# Adding hover CSS attributes via jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Some CSS styles need to be applied to an element on hover, and CSS styles have to be applied using javascript/jquery directly and not through stylesheets or `$(this).addClass('someStyle')` because I am injecting the DOM elements into another page.

We can apply the usual css styles using

```
$('#some-content').css({
    marginTop: '60px',
    display: 'inline-block'
});
```

How should we add the CSS styles for `:hover` events?

---

Do we have to resort to:

```
$('#some-content').hover(
       function(){ $(this).css('display', 'block') },
       function(){ $(this).css('display', 'none') }
)
```

Comment: Look the `.hover()` method in jquery. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: why not add and remove a class based on the hover event in jquery or onmouseover and onmouseout?

Comment: you want the element to disappear when you've hovered away from it?  How are you supposed to hover back onto it again?

Comment: @Alnitak Good point, i chose `display` attribute randomly, probably not a good example :)

Comment: Just to clarify.

If I understood original question is not how to **trigger** jQuery event on hover/hout, but rather how to decorate the hover style of an element with particular CSS attributes, etc.

However that is not possible, please see here more details: (jQuery Bug tracker: ACCESS :HOVER CSS PROPERTIES OF AN ELEMENT VIA JQUERY: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4434).
Therefore workarounds in other answers provided should be used instead.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I find using mouseenter and mouseleave to be better than hover. There's more control.

```
$("#somecontent").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#F00").css("border-radius", "3px");
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).css("background", "00F").css("border-radius", "0px");
});
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the "There's more control" statement? As far as I'm aware the `.hover()` function is just a shorthand for doing precisely what you've coded.

Comment: I just like the explicitness of it saying 'mouse entering the element' and 'mouse leaving the element'. However, the graphs on this page would suggest that live mouseenter/mouseleave is the best in terms of optimization. http://jsperf.com/hover-vs-mouseenter

Comment: @Jon great answer, very useful thanks. One quick thing, you forgot the "#" hash symbol on the hex color code for the `mouseleave` function, which is required for that bit of code to work.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
$('#some-content').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({ marginTop: '60px', display: 'inline-block' });
}, function(){
    $(this).css({ //other stuff });
});
```

or using classes

```
$('#some-content').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('newClass');
});
```

More info here [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 3):

You should put them in a [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover) event:

```javascript
var elem = $('#elem');

elem.hover(function () {
    // ... :hover, set styles
}, function () {
    // ... this function is called when the mouse leaves the item, set back the
    //     normal styles
});
```

However, I completely recommend to put your CSS in classes and use those classes in JS, you should split the languages as much as you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#someObj").hover(function(){
    $(this).css(...);
}:);
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This causes the css to stick after you move the mouse away.