# How to make each letter in word change on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So lets say I have a the word "IamGreat" somewhere within a paragraph on my website, and I want it to change to "Good4you" on hover. However, instead of changing the whole word, I want it so that each letter changes individually. Hence if I hover over the letter "I" it will turn into the letter "G", the letter "r" will turn into the number "4" etc. The two words are the same length. If possible I would also like to change the css (font color, font varient etc.)  of the letter which is being changed. Is there a way I can do this using jQuery or javascript?

Comment: You need each letter in a separate span. https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js can help do that if you want to automate it. You'd then loop through each span, change the contents, wait a bit, and move onto the next.

Comment: http://labs.bigroomstudios.com/libraries/animo-js

Comment: Shouldn't be very hard to do, here's a simple example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/y76c5/**

Comment: What have you tried? SO is for helping with coding problems, not doing all the design and coding for you.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Oh I was just wondering how I would go about doing this in the first place. What Rich said about using different span tags was enough to get me going. Sorry if my question didn't make that message clear. Also they may have been something out there that lets me do this in a few lines of code, that I simply didn't know about, so I was checking to see if something like that existed by asking here :)

Comment: @adeneo I don't know about your code.. but it messes up the entire word in chrome 37 xD

Answer (score 3):

```css
span {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(content);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 750ms;
  -moz-transition: all 750ms;
  -o-transition: all 750ms;
  transition: all 750ms;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
span:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg, 25deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(10deg, 25deg);
  transform: skew(10deg, 25deg);
}
```

```html
<span content="H">H</span>
<span content="o">o</span>
<span content="v">v</span>
<span content="e">e</span>
<span content="r">r</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go like with this scenario  in jquery

- get string lenght(to get indexes of all characters in string)
- get upper case characters and their indexes(A,B,C)
- so you go throught this array, when 1st upper case character is found, replace it with 1st character from 2nd string("good4you"), until the next upper case character, you will just "substring" the 1st string...
- how to apply CSS you have answer here [Adding hover CSS attributes via jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707134/adding-hover-css-attributes-via-jquery-javascript)

hope i give you some idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function inArray(value, array){
  for(var i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++){
    if(array[i] === value){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function wow(string, outputElement, beforeArray, afterArray){
  var s = string.split('');
  for(var i=0,l=s.length; i<l; i++){
    (function(i){
      var sp = doc.creatElement('span'), t = s[i];
      sp.innerHTML = t;
      sp.onmouseover = function(ev){
        var e = ev || event;
        var rt = e.relatedTarget;
        while(rt && rt !== sp){
          rt = rt.parentNode;
        }
        if(rt !== sp && inArray(t, beforeArray) && afterArray[beforeArray.indexOf(t)]){
          sp.innerHTML = afterArray[beforeArray.indexOf(t)];
        }
      }
      sp.onmouseout = function(ev){
        var e = ev || event;
        var rt = e.relatedTarget;
        while(rt && rt !== sp){
          rt = rt.parentNode;
        }
        if(rt !== sp){
          sp.innerHTML = t;
        }
      }
      outputElement.appendChild(sp);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

The `wow` function I made creates spans adding their backward compatible `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` Events automatically. To style those spans you could make `sp.className = 'over';` `onmouseover` and `sp.className = 'default';` `onmouseout`, and have the CSS already made accordingly. For individual styling you'll have to add more Arrays to the `wow` function. `sp` might as well be `this` inside `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

```
// appends to id='someId'
wow('Just Adding Some Random Text', E('someId'), ['J', 'T'], ['M', 'S']);
```