# How to use JavaScript to get the specific character under cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, text, google-chrome-extension

For example, if I have `<p>Hello world</p>` and my cursor is on `e`, how could I know that?

Update

Thank you so much for all of your comments. I don't want to change it, but to get two information: the char, in this case "e" and it's position (x and y). I'll use them for other purposes. I'm also making it for a Chrome extension so that I cannot change the original HTML tags.

Comment: What do you mean by "my cursor is on `e`"?

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: Put every letter in a span and place an onmouseover event handler on it.

Comment: [How to make each letter in word change on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471132)

Comment: You can get some idea from [How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make each letter in word change on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471132/how-to-make-each-letter-in-word-change-on-hover)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your comments. I don't want to change it, but to get two information: the char, in this case "e" and it's position (x and y). I'll use them for other purposes. I'm also making it for a Chrome extension so that I cannot change the original HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can put every letter in a `span` element, then add a `onmouseover`event to it.

Like this:

```js
  function func1(){
   document.writeln("H");
  }
  function func2(){
   document.writeln("e");
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p><span onmouseover="func1();">H</span><span onmouseover="func2();">e</span>llo World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it also replaces the text that was already there.