# Is there anyway to add hover effect to the table row elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**I'm using javascript to add rows into my html table and coz of that I can't change style properties using css.**

**To add backgroud color I used**

```
r = document.getElementById("table").insertRow();
r.style.background="flouralwhite"
```

**But I couldn't find a way to change the background color when I hover on it. Is there a way to do it.**

Comment: Why can't you change style properties using css? If you're creating rows in javascript, could you give them classes when you create them?

Comment: This seems like maybe a dupe/similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707134/adding-hover-css-attributes-via-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use use :-

```
const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
// add td in it if you wish 
// add class to this row
tableRow.className = "hoverAble";
```

now in your css file add the styling -

```
hoverable:hover {
   background-colour:"flouralwhite";
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for .